# Ya que no es extranjerismo, ¿qué es "puenting" gramaticalmente como palabra con sonido inglés?

Tags: sustantivos

Acabo de descubrir que la RAE tiene en su diccionario la palabra *puenting*:

> [**puenting**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UZz0V6Q)
>   *De puente y el ingl. -ing, sufijo de acción, por analogía con rafting, jogging, etc.*
>   1. m. Deporte de riesgo que consiste en tirarse al vacío desde un puente u otro lugar elevado, sujetándose con una cuerda elástica.

Ya sabéis, esto:

> [image]

Tiene gracia la palabra, pues parece que sea inglesa, pero realmente no. Allí utilizan *bungee jumping*. De hecho, tal y como comenta el diccionario, surge de la contracción de una palabra española (*puente*) con el sufijo inglés *-ing*.

Dado que la palabra no existe en inglés, no es un [extranjerismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HOauPO6), ni tampoco un préstamo lingüístico.

¿De qué se trata pues? ¿Existe algún nombre para definir la palabra que suena a otro idioma pero que no es más que una mezcla de una local más un afijo que le da un toque extranjero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Puenting" es un claro ejemplo de [préstamo gramatical](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9stamo_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstico#Pr.C3.A9stamo_gramatical).

En lugar de adoptarse la palabra inglesa en su totalidad (en cuyo caso se trataría de un préstamo liso y llano), se toma el morfema "-ing" que sirve para la formación del gerundio en inglés y es utilizado en esa lengua para designar la actividad correspondiente al verbo.

Coincido en que es un modo muy novedoso de construcción morfológica que permite replicar términos similares propios del inglés. Seguramente en este caso ha primado, por encima de la decisión de adoptar un préstamo completo, la conveniencia de dotar a la palabra de un sufijo que dé a entender que se trata de una actividad deportiva pero conservando la raíz española (puente).

Comment: ¡Gracias Gustavson! Qué gozada de respuestas que estás ofreciendo :) Creo que ahora ya pudes comentar por todo jeje.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @fedorqui. El foro tiene muy buen nivel y da gusto participar. Respecto de los comentarios que me habían eliminado, he conseguido reciclarlos e incorporarlos a respuestas propiamente dichas. Nada se pierde, todo se transforma, jaja.

Comment: Hay gente con mucho conocimiento por aquí, siempre es un reto ver qué se pregunta e intentar responderlo. Probablemente puedas ver tus respuestas borradas en http://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/14676 De allí puedes extraer la información que quieras añadir en comentarios o subsiguientes respuestas. En caso que no las veas y tengas necesidad de recuperar algo de allí, coméntamelo y las desborro un rato. Nos vemos por aquí :)

Comment: Por cierto, veo en tu perfil que eres traductor técnico, entre otras cosas. Puede resultarte interesante navegar por http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%C3%A9cnico+traducci%C3%B3n para encontrar preguntas interesantes y/o temas que te hayas encontrado en el pasado y a los que puedas aportar tu experiencia.

Comment: Será un placer. Soy muy novato en este foro y poco a poco lo iré conociendo mejor. Gracias por tus sugerencias.

Comment: El nombre para definir la palabra que suena a otro idioma pero que no es más que una mezcla de una local más un afijo que le da un toque extranjero ¿Puede ser _espanglish_? Según Wikipedia el [espanglish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espanglish) es _la fusión morfosintáctica y semántica del español con el inglés estadounidense. Es un fenómeno lingüístico similar al llanito utilizado en Gibraltar. Suele confundirse con el uso de anglicismos en español._

Comment: No, el espanglish consiste en adaptar una palabra o expresión inglesa de modo que tenga apariencia de español. Por ejemplo, "vacunar la carpeta" por "vacuum the carpet" (en lugar del correcto "aspirar la alfombra").